# How to give route access for same menu for two different user roles using AuthGuard in Angular?

Tags: angular

I have an application with three user roles : ROLE_USER, ROLE_MODERATOR AND ROLE_ADMIN like below:

```
export enum Role {
    User = 'ROLE_USER',
    Moderator = 'ROLE_MODERATOR',
    Admin = 'ROLE_ADMIN'
}
```

I have menu called "profile" which is accessible to ROLE_MODERATOR and ROLE_ADMIN. This menu can be seen after successful login for both Moderator and Admin. And I am using AuthGuard to restrict unauthorized users to access profile menu, in this case only moderator and admin can access it. I have placed AuthGuard for profile menu in my app.module.ts file as below:

```
path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuardService], data: { roles: [Role.Admin, Role.Moderator] }, pathMatch: 'full' }
```

My User class is as below:

```
export class User {
    username: string;
    password: string;
    role: Role;
}
```

And my AuthGuard class is as below:

```
export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate {
  isLoggedIn: boolean;

  constructor(private router: Router,
    private tokenService: TokenStorageService,
    private auth: AuthService) { }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    const currentUser = this.tokenService.getUser();
    this.isUserLoggedIn = this.tokenService.getToken();

    if (this.isLoggedIn) {
      if (currentUser.roles == 'ROLE_ADMIN' || currentUser.roles == 'ROLE_MODERATOR') {
        return true;
      }
      this.router.navigate(['/']);
      return false;
    }
  }

  isUserLoggedInn() {
    if (this.tokenService.getToken()) {
      this.isLoggedIn = true;
    }
  }
}
```

In code above there is simple logic where it will be checked if user is logged in. If user is logged in, it will check for current user role. If user's role is Admin or Moderator, it should be able to access profile menu from their respective accounts which I hope I have rightly configured in app.module.ts class for profile menu. But it is not not working as expected so I am doing something wrong here. Any help or suggestion would be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `currentUser.roles`? Just to confirm the `currentUser` data type is `User`. And what you try to do is obtaining the **data roles** from the route and validate that `currentUser` must have one of these roles to access the page, is it correct?

Comment: currentUser is loggedIn  user. It takes roles value from token. Yes currentUser data type is User. I am taking role from token and try to access route on basis of currentUser role i.e if user logged in as Admin would access profile route and also Moderator would access profile afte successful login. That is why i have kept this logic                               if (currentUser.roles == 'ROLE_ADMIN' || currentUser.roles == 'ROLE_MODERATOR') . May be I am doing wrong i do not know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you are passing the 'allowed roles' in via the route using `data'. However, you're not using that in your guard.

```
data: { roles: [Role.Admin, Role.Moderator] }
```

You can make the guard dynamic for any role (and future roles) by doing the following:

```
export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate {
    isLoggedIn: boolean;
  
    constructor(private router: Router,
      private tokenService: TokenStorageService,
      private auth: AuthService) { }
  
    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
      // Gets the roles from route data
      const roles = route.data['roles'] as Array<string>;

      const currentUser = this.tokenService.getUser();
      this.isUserLoggedIn = this.tokenService.getToken();
  
      if (this.isUserLoggedIn) {
        
        // Considering currentUser.roles is a single value and not an array 
        for (let i = 0; i < roles.length; i++) {
            if (currentUser.roles == roles[i]) {
                return true
            }
        }

        // Considering currentUser.roles is an array of roles allotted to the user, then uncomment the below code
        // for (let i = 0; i < roles.length; i++) {
        //     if (currentUser.roles.findIndex(x => x.roleName == roles[i]) != -1) {
        //         return true;
        //     }
        // }

        this.router.navigate(['/']);
        return false;
      }
    }

  }
```

Comment: Yeah I was not using allowed roles in my logic. Now its working. Thank You.